# How to write /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list to install mongodb on ubuntu focal fossa?

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, software-sources, mongodb

I am trying to clone and work on freeCodeCamp locally on my Ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa. When I reach step to install mongodb community. On mongdb official documentation and installation guide they have teached about insalling mongodb on ubuntu 18 bionic by making /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list file and echoing this line in that file : `https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse` .
Full command is   `echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list` 
I tried to get this for Focal Fossa by editing this  `https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse`     to
`https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/mongodb-org/development/multiverse/`
But this occurs error while updating and installing.
Is there any proper way to edit this sources.list file for focal fossa so that we can install mongodb properly for ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/development multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list
```

If there's still an error, maybe you should post the log from apt

Comment: W: GPG error: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/development Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 253612A09571B484
E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/development Release' is not signed.

This error on : ``` sudo apt update ```

Comment: I have also change this command: wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo apt-key add -    to 
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -

4.4 but getting error on updating and also on running this command : sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

this error occurs : Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org